# Docker Consul Multiple Containers in single VM setup

Tags: docker, containers, consul

Docker commands that I have used to spin the consul container-

1. Created static Ip for container 1 = `docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 C1`
2. Run a consul container to that Ip:
   `docker run -d --net C1 --ip 172.18.0.10 -p 48301:8301/tcp  -p 48400:8400/tcp  -p 48600:8600/tcp -p 48300:8300/tcp -p 48302:8302/tcp -p 48302:8302/udp -p 48500:8500/tcp -p 48600:8600/udp -p 48301:8301/udp --name=test1 consul agent -client=172.18.0.10 -bind=172.18.0.10 -server -bootstrap -ui`
3. Similarly created static Ip for containter 2 - `docker network create --subnet=172.19.0.0/16 C2`
4. `docker run -d --net C2 --ip 172.19.0.10 -p 58301:8301/tcp  -p 58400:8400/tcp  -p 58600:8600/tcp -p 58300:8300/tcp -p 58302:8302/tcp -p 58302:8302/udp -p 58500:8500/tcp -p 58600:8600/udp -p 58301:8301/udp --name=test2 consul agent -client=172.19.0.10 -bind=172.19.0.10 -server -bootstrap -ui -join 192.168.99.100:48301`

The consul container test2 at IP 172.19.0.10:8301 is not able to gossip with the 172.18.0.10:8301. I get the No Acknowledgement received message.

I also tried the --link to link both containers. But that didn't work.

Can anyone let me know if I am doing everything correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a user-defined network on the docker daemon, there are some properties of these networks that you have to be aware of.

> Each container in the network can immediately communicate with other containers in the network. Though, the network itself **isolates** the containers from external networks. [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/)

That effectively says what you are experiencing. The containers can not talk to each other because they are **isolated** from each other (reside in different networks).

To the point of `--link`, it is not supported in user-defined networks.

> Within a user-defined bridge network, linking is not supported. [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/)

The solution would be to simply put both containers in the same network. I don't see an apparent need to use two different networks from your description. Just use a different `--ip` for the second one.